# NPE while using Custom Logging in Jetty 10/11

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, application-server, jetty-10

I am implementing Custom logging in Jetty11 and getting the null pointer exception for the below code while fetching anything from the request object.
I know the reason but do not the solution to it. The reason is: calling the request object methods before setting it.
I know, there should be another way to do it.
My use case is to set the int and string attributes to the logger. In this example, I am calling request.getMethod() but I also have to call other methods as well

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;

    public class JettyCustomLogger extends CustomRequestLog
    {
        private static Request request;
    
        @Override
        public void log(Request request, Response response)
        {
            this.request = request;
            super.log(request, response);
        }
    
        public JettyCustomLogger(Writer writer, String logStr)
        {
            super(writer, setCustomAttributesToLog(logStr));
        }
    
        private static String setCustomAttributesToLog(String logStr)
        {
    
            String method = request.getMethod();
            StringBuilder logBuffer = new StringBuilder(logStr);
            logBuffer.append(method);
            logBuffer.append("Ashish");
            logBuffer.append(" ");
            logBuffer.append("Goyanka");
            logBuffer.append(" ");
            logBuffer.append("absgdh");
            logBuffer.append(" ");
    
            return logBuffer.toString();
        }
    
    }
```

Note: this code works fine if I don't call request object methods.

Update: the reason to create setCustomAttributesToLog() is that I need to fetch the string parameters from other methods on runtime but here, I have given hardcoded string for code readability

Answer (score 1):

The `log(request, response)` method is called for every request response pair, this method is expected to produce some formatted log string and then give it to the `RequestLogWriter`. You should not be using `setCustomAttributesToLog()` in the constructor as there is no request yet, and you should not be storing the request as a static field. All your logic to convert produce the log string based on the request must be done in the `log()` method.

For your current implementation, there should be no reason you cannot use the standard `CustomRequestLog`. If you read the javadoc on this class there is the concept of the format string. The format string is generic and takes % codes to be replaced with information from an actual request/response.

To get what you're trying to achieve here you could do something like

```java
CustomRequestLog requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(writer, "%m Ashnish Goyanka absgdh ")
```

Then for each request the `%m` will be replaced with the request method, then this string will be given to the writer.

---

If you do not wish to use the format string functionality of `CustomRequestLog` I would suggest you implement the `RequestLog` interface directly instead of extending `CustomRequestLog`.

Comment: I do not understand this point -  All your logic to convert produce the log string based on the request must be done in the log() method - I can not do that because we don't have Writer writer, String logStr objects in the log(request, response) method. Can you please explain more if it is possible.

Comment: Just save the Writer as a field in the constructor. You can't log a request in the constructor because there is no Request to log. The request/response pairs to log are given to you in the log() method.

Comment: There is actually a getWriter() method on CustomRequestLog which you can call to get the Writer, so you don't need to save it as a field yourself.